# Object On Characters Back Follows Character but Not In Unity

Tags: bones, unity, parent

I have a backpack object attached to my character model in Blender.  It is parented to the armature, and then the chest bone.  It moves well with the character in Blender completely fine.  But when I export to Unity, it doesn't want to follow anymore along with the animations.

The weird part is that I also have a weapon slot with the exact same settings as the backpack, and it works fine in Blender and in Unity.

I've applied all transforms, and both the backpack and weapon slots origins are at world origin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out.  Turns out I did not have my backpack meshes vertices assigned to the chest bone in weight paint